Add Shopify embed app offers section above "Add to Cart" button
I'm building a Shopify embed app using React that displays product offers (discounts, bundles, etc.). I need to integrate this app into the product page layout, specifically positioning the offers section directly above the "Add to Cart" button.
I've gone through the Shopify documentation, but I'm unsure how to target and inject my app's content into that specific location on the product page.
Is there a way to automatically add my app's offers block above the "Add to Cart" button without requiring manual intervention from the merchant? If so, how can I achieve this positionin?
I moved to app embed because app block dont support theme 1.0
